# Como fazer um select com vários resultados em um só linha

Tags: mysql, sql

**O problema:** Um de nossos sites tem um sistema de mensagens entre os usuários, para isto temos duas tabelas: uma que guarda as mensagens entre os usuários e outra com os usuário, seguem as estruturas abaixo,e com estes dados precisamos exibir nas mensagens o nome de todos os usuários para qual a mensagem foi enviada.

No inicio pensei em fazer um *select* para as mensagens e com a id dos usuários desta mensagem gerar uma outra cadeia de *select's* dentro de um *while*, porém isso me parecia errado e pesquisando pela internet não achei nenhuma alternativa para esta situação. Alguém teria uma solução para este problema? Teria como fazer um único *select* para pegar tanto o nome dos usuários quanto a mensagem?

**Seguem as estruturas:**

TABELA mensagens:

- id INT PRIMARY KEY,
- id_users: 'Relaciona com o id do usuário, Ex: 1,27,1247,88',
- title 'titulo da mensagem',
- text 'texto da mensagem',

TABELA users:

- id INT PRIMARY KEY,
- name 'nome do usuario',
- etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo que você crie uma SQL pra isso, ela vai te custar muito processamento, pois você vai ter que quebrar essa string `id_users` em uma lista, e fazer um JOIN em cima dela.

O que eu sugiro é que você refaça sua estrutura, usando a forma como a grande maioria dos sistemas funcionam nesta situação. Desta forma:

**TABELA mensagens:**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
title 'titulo da mensagem',
text 'texto da mensagem',
```

**TABELA users:**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name 'nome do usuario',
```

**TABELA users_mensagens:**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY
id_user (FK)
id_mensagem (FK)
```

É uma estrutura super básica Many-to-Many, ou seja, uma mensagem pode pertencer a 1 ou mais usuários, e um usuário pode ter 1 ou mais mensagens. Com isso, sua query fica desta forma:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, m.id
    FROM users u
    JOIN users_mensagens um ON um.id_users = u.`id`
    JOIN mensagens m ON m.id = um.id_mensagens;
```

Comment: o problema é que essa query me retorna apenas o nome de um dos usuário e uma mensagem pode ter até 20 usuários vinculados a ela... =/

Comment: Opa, perai, agora que percebi, o valor do campo id_users é uma string com os ids separados por vírgula?

Comment: isso mesmo @rafaels88!

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta pra você.

Answer (score 2):

Um amigo (@rodrigoborth) me ajudou falando sobre o 'FIND_IN_SET', o qual me fez chegar na seguinte query:

```
SELECT mensagens.id, users.name, mensagens.title, mensagens.date
    FROM mensagens INNER JOIN users
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET( users.id , mensagens.id_users ) ORDER BY mensagens.id
```

Simplificando meu problema e assim temporariamente respondendo a pergunta! =)

Comment: Isso ajudou um bocado já :D

Answer (score 1):

Seu banco de dados parece desnormalizado, aconselho se possível, a criação de uma tabela para relacionar o usuário a mensagem. Mas segue uma opção utilizando uma subconsulta para trazer os usuários relacionados a mensagem, reduzindo o número de linhas de resultado da consulta.

```
SELECT
m.title,
m.text,
m.id_users,
(
  SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ';')
  FROM users u 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id,m.id_users)
) as nomes
FROM mensagens m
```

Neste caso a consulta retorna os usuários relacionados a mensagem no formato `usuario1;usuário2`

Exemplo: **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac9b1/28)**

Comment: Duvida: Isto não vai gerar uma consulta lenta, mesmo eu aplicando a ideia do @rafaels88 à sua resposta?

Comment: @MateusDemboski minha resposta baseia-se na sua estrutura atual, como eu disse, o correto é você criar uma tabela para o relacionamento das entidades.

Comment: então é essa minha ideia, cria a tabela para o relacionamento e usar parte da sua query para gerar o resultado, pois é exatamente isso que sua query faz oque eu preciso, porém, me bateu a dúvida se isso não geraria uma consulta lenta

Comment: @MateusDemboski Entendi, mais se vai gerar uma consulta lenta depende de N fatores.

Comment: @MateusDemboski, o ideal é você fazer este tipo de processamento, de juntar com ;, no seu código da aplicação, e não no SQL. O SQL não tem que ser responsável pela lógica dos dados. Se você futuramente quiser portar seu sistema para outro server que não tenha a função FIND_IN_SET, seu sistema não vai funcionar. Mas se você fizer isto no código, e não no SQL, você nunca passará por isso.

Comment: @rafaels88, como eu disse, minha resposta foi baseado na estrutura atual, é a maneira que encontrei de retornar a consulta conforme ele deseja, também concordo que esta não é a melhor maneira de fazer, mais depende, se o sistema atual já esta em produção e não pode-se alterar o banco para criar uma nova tabela, esta seria uma saída.

Comment: @abfurlan Compreendi completamente o que você quis dizer, e concordo plenamente. Meu comentário foi destinado ao MateusDemboski mesmo. Se ele tem a possibilidade de alterar isso, é melhor fazer antes que vire um grande macarrão. =)

Comment: @rafaels88 entendido, acho que combinamos que não é a melhor maneira :P